# .js file detected as type:html when called by HTML script. "was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type."

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rest

I have seen this MIME type error before but no solutions that I have seen here are helping.

I have been trying to get an API post to work for a bit now, and this is the final key to my puzzle I think.

I have 3 files:

- Node JS file: server.js which is run by running 'node server.js' in the root directory of the site.
- HTML file: index.html
- Javascript file: script.js which is brought in by the HTML and is actively listening for a button to be pressed

When running this from the HTML file directly, it runs fine but im getting a CORS error that is caused by not running it through a backend.

When I run it from my Node.js server file, it has these errors at first load of the HTML page:

```
The script from “http://localhost:8000/script.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' script.js 1:1
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. The network tab in dev tools also calls the script.js an HTML file.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>REST API POST</title>
  <!-- <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button target="#post">POST to API</button>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const cors = require('cors')

let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            respone.write('Whoops! File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
};

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000);
```

script.js:

```
const triggerAPI = document.querySelectorAll('[target]')

triggerAPI.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    postToAPI()
  })
})

function postToAPI() {
  console.log("this is bleep!")
  fetch('https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/67541785/task', {
        method: 'post',
        body:    JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'pk_9326_5JD2PZO42X1XLZI2NCOZL08HIB3YY6DM', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}

const body = {
  "name": "Test from HTML code :)",
  "description": "New Task Description"
};
```

Update 1:

```
app.use(express.static(''));
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.listen(8000)
```

**Update 2:**
**Folder setup:**

- website (folder)

  - public

    - index.html
    - package-lock.json
    - package.json
    - script.js
  - server.js

**What am I doing?**

cd website

node server.js

**What error is happening?**

The resource from “http://localhost:8000/server.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

update 2 server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('/index.html')
})

app.listen(8000)
```

Update 3:

Right now, its working except its hitting:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/6/task. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/6/task. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

script.js:

```
const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[target]')

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    postToAPI()
  })
})

function postToAPI() {
  console.log("this is bleep!")
  fetch('https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/list/67541785/task', {
        method: 'post',
        body:    JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'pk_10219326_5JD2PZO42X1XLZI2NCOZL08HIB3YY6DM', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}

const body = {
  "name": "Test from HTML code :)",
  "description": "New Task Description"
};
```

Server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('/index.html')
})

app.listen(8000)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>REST API POST</title>
  <!-- <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <!-- <script defer src="script.js"></script> -->
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button target="#post">POST to API</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you tried accessing http://localhost:8000/script.js to see if it really outputs your js?

Comment: When I run that, it seems to still post that MIME type error. The same errors actually. @EliasSoares

Comment: The error when i go right to script.js https://imgur.com/a/AXg1QTD

Comment: Just noticed something @EliasSoares, when I went to view the source of the JS file, it just showed me the HTML. I think my NodeJS server is causing this! 

https://imgur.com/a/9SAFNOB

Comment: With `http.createServer(handleRequest)` you instructed your server program to respond to *every* single request, no matter what path, with the `index.html` contents and `'Content-Type': 'text/html'`. Please check the readme of expressjs on how to use it - currently you may create an `app`, but you never use the value anywhere.

Comment: will check that out right now @Bergi, thank you!!

Comment: @Bergi I re-wrote the server.js to be written in ExpressJS (what i originally wanted to do) and i'm having a different issue.
The HTML page loads with "The resource from “http://localhost:8000/script.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).localhost:8000" as an error. 

new code: https://pastebin.com/0AaT9jGx

Answer (score 0):

You're not using express correctly, don't try and run your own server if you're using express, do one or the other.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Here you've told express to serve your static files for you so just put .js and .html in /public and it's done, it'll all work automagically.  Static files are .html, .js, .css and similar files, express routes should serve logic while static files like .html can be directly served on server request.  By using the above line you're telling express to serve all static files from the /public directory so if you just put your .js and .html files in there you won't even need routes.

```
http.createServer(handleRequest)
```

That line is also handling every single request ever made to the server, so when your .html file hits the client's browser and it requests the .js file it will force it to serve the .html file that you've manually read off disk and never serve the .js file.  This will be avoided if you just put .js in /public.

```
app.get('/example', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile('./index.html')
})

...

app.listen(4000)
```

That's an example of how you want to listen for routes and how you can manually send a file using express.  Even though that will also never execute (I think) since .html will look for html in /public because of the static declaration.

Comment: Thank you! What exactly do you mean by put .js and .html in /public? Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, very new to Javascript and Node obviously. I am still a bit confused what you mean by 'This will be avoided if you just put .js in /public.' I have the files all in my root, but im sure thats not what you mean.

Comment: No problem.  On a server or an API you can serve mainly two different things, data and static files.  On typical routes like /example you'll return some sort of data, but for files like images, html pages, javascript files, css files and other things that never change you serve them from a static directory.  In this case you told express to serve all your static files, html, js, css, images, etc, from /public.  So whenever you now send a server request to the server for any of those files it will look for it in /public so if you just move it there it will automatically find it and serve it.

Comment: I see. So if that is the case, wouldn't I leave it like this? I just posted Update 1 in the main post.

Comment: No.  You should create a /public directory and any .html or .js files you have should be in there, your server itself should never serve any .html files.  Remove all the code for the manual .html file reading you've done and just put that .html file in /public  So you should have /public/index.html and /public/script.js and you're done.  After that remove everything you've done and with just the app.use(express.static('public')); line it'll work automatically because express will serve it for you.

Comment: Does it matter where this directory is located? At the moment I have this running in a Folder called 'website' in my Documents folder. If it doesn't matter I'll just throw a new folder called "public" in there.

Comment: Yes it has to be in the root directory of your project because that's what you told express.  So you'll have /website/public/index.html.  If you want to change that you can specify a different path where you told express to find static files.

Comment: Thank you! I just followed those directions but am still running into an error when I go to localhost:8000 after running node server.js at the root folder. the HTML loads fine.

Comment: just updated with current server.js file in update 2.

Comment: NEVERMIND, i made a dumb typo. 

We are in the homestretch now. Now i am getting a CORS policy error. gonna update the code with Update 3 now.


Updated with update 3